# Multiview vs Wizard Control

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to take multiple inputs from user in multiple steps.

Which approach is better? Multiview or Wizard control?

What is the basic difference between them. can any body guide me in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a Wizard control, as long as the experience is informative and usable. It is a typical process and I would guess most users are familiar with the approach.

Before heading straight into the development it would be ideal to map our the flow and information you want captured in each step. Then decide how persistent the wizard should be - can the user come back to the same place when saving a draft, do all pages need to be completed before saving, how are transactions handled.

For tips on design you can look over some Smashing Magazine articles.